# How to Enable/Disable Menu Item 2 in OnUpdate Handler of Menu Item 1?

Tags: mfc

I have two menu items. When item 1 is disabled, I want item 2 to be disabled as well. In the OnUpdate handler of menu item 1, I have tried to use "t_pMenu = pCmdUI->m_pMenu;", "t_pMenu = pCmdUI->m_pSubMenu;" and "t_pMenu = pCmdUI->m_pParentMenu;" but I always get NULL t_pMenu. How can I achieve this purpose?

```
void CDummyView::OnUpdateMenuItem1(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) 
{
    if(m_bShowMenuItem1)
    {
        pCmdUI->SetText("Hide Features")
        CMenu * t_pMenu = pCmdUI->m_pSubMenu;
        if(t_pMenu != NULL)
            t_pMenu->EnableMenuItem(ID_MENU_ITEM2, MF_ENABLED);
    }
    else 
    {
        pCmdUI->SetText("Show Features")
        CMenu * t_pMenu = pCmdUI->m_pParentMenu;
        if(t_pMenu != NULL)
            t_pMenu->EnableMenuItem(ID_MENU_ITEM2, MF_GRAYED);
    }
}

void CDummyView::OnUpdateMenuItem2(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Add `pCmdUI->Enable(m_bShowMenuItem1);` to `OnUpdateMenuItem2`,   and remove all the `CMenu*` stuff from `OnUpdateMenuItem1`

Answer (score 0):

Never handle to different command IDs in one handler.
Each handler is called more than once if there are buttons and menu items. Also you don't know the sequence. When you alter the item2 in Item1 handler it may be enabled again when the handler for Item2 is called later.

When you have a flag named m_bShowMenuItem1 just use it.

```
void CDummyView::OnUpdateMenuItem1(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) 
{
    pCmdUI->Enable(m_bShowMenuItem1);
}

void CDummyView::OnUpdateMenuItem2(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable(m_bShowMenuItem1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it work.  Below is the code I tried.  Two flag variables m_bShowFeatures and m_bShowSmallFetures are initialized to be TRUE.

```
void CDummyView::OnMenuItem1()
{
    m_bShowFeatures = !m_bShowFeatures;
    m_pDoc->UpdateAllViews(NULL, SHOW_HIDE_ALL_FEATURES);
}

void CDummyView::OnUpdateMenuItem1(CCmdUI* pCmdUI) 
{
    if(m_bShowFeatures)
        pCmdUI->SetText("Hide Features")
    else 
        pCmdUI->SetText("Show Features")
}

void CDummyView::OnMenuItem2()
{
    m_bShowSmallFetures= !m_bShowSmallFetures;
    m_pDoc->UpdateAllViews(NULL, SHOW_HIDE_SMALL_FEATURES);
}

void CDummyView::OnUpdateMenuItem2(CCmdUI* pCmdUI)
{
    pCmdUI->Enable(m_bShowFetures)
    if(m_bShowSmallFetures)
        pCmdUI->SetText("Hide Small Features")
    else 
        pCmdUI->SetText("Show Small Features")
}
```

So OnUpdateMenuItem2() does get invoked after OnMenuItem1() is called when Menu Item 1 is clicked.  I didn't expect that.